# fading in fading out images with toggleClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image

Here's a script that is working as a simple carousel to fade in and fade out a few images when the `prev` and `next` buttons are clicked.

I successfully achieved the fading in and fade out by using the jQuery `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` methods.

```
var speed = 100;

$('.prev').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); 

    var current = $(this).parent().next('ul.images').children(':visible'),
    lastSib = $(this).parent().next('ul.images').children(':last'),
    prevSib = current.prev();

    prevSib = prevSib.index() == -1 ? lastSib : prevSib; 

    current.fadeOut(speed,function(){
        prevSib.fadeIn(speed);
    });

});
```

I decided to try another solution to fading each image by using css for fading effects by toggling classes with the `toggleClass()` method. Here is where my problem occurs...**The only** image that fades now is the first image. I don't have access to any other images anymore.

I'm speculating that I might need to loop through each image and approach this solution a little differently.

Here's a link the [codepen](http://codepen.io/kapena/pen/zroMmP)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var speed = 100;

    $('.prev').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault(); 

        var current = $(this).parent().next('ul.images').children(':visible'),
        lastSib = $(this).parent().next('ul.images').children(':last'),
        prevSib = current.prev();
        prevSib = prevSib.index() == -1 ? lastSib : prevSib; 

     // fading out fading in  
        current.toggleClass('out');
        prevSib.toggleClass('in');
    });

$('.next').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var current = $(this).parent().next('ul.images').children(':visible'),
    firstSib = $(this).parent().next('ul.images').children(':first'),
    nextSib = current.next();

    nextSib = nextSib.index() == -1 ? firstSib : nextSib; 

        current.toggleClass('out');
        nextSib.toggleClass('in');
});

$('.images li').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var firstImg = $(this).parent().children(':first'),
            nextImg = $(this).next();

    nextImg = nextImg.index() == -1 ? firstImg : nextImg;

    $(this).toggleClass('out');
    nextImg.toggleClass('in');

    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I have made some changes in your CSS and JQuery code. Use these updated code, it will help you to meet your requirement.

CSS Code

```
        .images li{
            list-style:none;
            display:none;
        }

        .images li:first-child{
            display: block;
        }

        li{
            transition:opacity 0.4s;
            opacity:1;
        }

        .out{
            transition:opacity 0.2s;
            opacity:0;
            display:none !important;
        }

        .in{
            transition:opacity 0.4s;
            opacity:1;
            display:list-item !important;
        }
```

JQuery Code for your next and previous Click Event

```
$('.prev').click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault(); 

            var current = $(this).parent().next('ul.images').children(':visible'),
            lastSib = $(this).parent().next('ul.images').children(':last'),
            prevSib = current.prev();

            // true previous 
            prevSib = prevSib.index() == -1 ? lastSib : prevSib; 

            current.removeAttr('class');
            current.toggleClass('out');
            prevSib.toggleClass('in');
        });

        $('.next').click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();

            var current = $(this).parent().next('ul.images').children(':visible'),
            firstSib = $(this).parent().next('ul.images').children(':first'),
            nextSib = current.next();

            // true next 
            nextSib = nextSib.index() == -1 ? firstSib : nextSib; 

            current.removeAttr('class');
            current.toggleClass('out');
            nextSib.toggleClass('in');
        });
```